# How to use a different data model with EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am not even sure how to ask this question. I am absolutely willing to research this myself, but I don't even know what exactly my options are.

I'm fairly new to programming in general, and I'm the sole developer on an ASP.NET MVC3 web application. We're about to upgrade to a new version which has a lot of addition to the data model. There are a couple new entities and some of the old entities have new properties/columns.

We've finished beta testing and now we're going to try to get everyone moved over to the new version running parallel to the current version, that way if there are show-stopping problems, users can easily switch back to the old version. The problem is that we can't hook both up to the same db because of the data model differences.

Can I make the old version use the new version's schema or something? I'm not really sure what my options are. I'm not asking you to write this for me; I'm just looking for some direction. Thanks!

Comment: are you using code first? Also, do you want to use the same Db? (and have different code versions) as that could lead to undesirable effects. I'm guessing you'd like to 'share' the data

Comment: Yes to code first. I was thinking of using the same Db. What's difference between "sharing" and "using"?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable the metadata checks and then use two versions against the DB assuming the models use a schema that is compatible between both.

http://revweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/ef-4-1-code-first-disable-checking-for-edmmetadata-table/

Another option is to use entity framework 4.3 code first migrations and actually use an upgrade script that it will generate for you. If it fails you can roll back the script to a prior version and use your prior code base. This would imply you upgrade to 4.3 first before doing anything else though although you could still disable metadata checks.